# Changing the color of a supportActionBar programmatically

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I'm having an issue where changing the background drawable of the support ActionBar changes the color of most of the bar but leaves the old color around the text and icons. I've tried changing the color of the support ActionBar and the ToolBar that I used to make it. I've tried many different ways of invalidating the UI elements. I've tired setting the color and text is different orders. I've tried hiding and showing the text. I just can't make it turn to one solid color.

[image: Should be all orange]

Here's what I have for my ActionBar style:

```
<style name="LocationBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_color_primary_inverse</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/text_color_primary_inverse</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/weather_cool</item>
</style>
```

This is how I'm adding it to my activity:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/location_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/LocationBar"/>
```

This in the Java code I set it as the supportActionBar:

```
_locationBar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.location_bar);
setSupportActionBar(_locationBar);
```

Then after I fetch the weather I try to adjust the color like this:

```
ColorDrawable warmDrawable = new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.weather_warm));
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(warmDrawable);
```

Which results in what you see in the picture. Most of the bar changes color but not all of it.

Comment: Can you share your `styles.xml`?

Comment: Changing theme can work here.

Comment: I add a lot more information. Sorry about that, it was late and I wasn't thinking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...changing the background drawable of the support ActionBar changes the
>   color of most of the bar but leaves the old color around the text and
>   icons...

The reason this is happening is because you're using `android:theme` instead of `style`. `theme` gets applied to every child in your `Toolbar`, in this case including the `TextView` title background and your settings button background. `style` is meant to be used at the view level and will only be applied to your `Toolbar` background.

**Before**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    ...
    android:theme="@style/LocationBar" />
```

**After**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    ...
    style="@style/LocationBar" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Write code in your activity class as follows.

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#004D40")));
```

This will change background color as **`#004D40`**

Comment: This is what I'm doing and getting the result in the picture.